# Visual Studio 2013 Find by Wildcard

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013, replace

In previos versions of VS I was able to use simple wildcards in a search pattern, e.g. the search for `,*)"` would find any string between a comma and a closing parantesis. This was very useful in situations e.g. where you had a list of SQL Command parameters and you needed to reedit this list into a list of parameters in a function call:

```
            With .Parameters
                .Add("@MandID", MySqlDbType.Int32)
                .Add("@LiefID", MySqlDbType.Int32)
                .Add("@BestellNummer", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                .Add("@vcTransactionID", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                .Add("@vcStatus", MySqlDbType.Int16)
                .Add("@BestellStatusID", MySqlDbType.Int32)
                .Add("@BestellDatum", MySqlDbType.Date)
                .Add("@BestellNetto", MySqlDbType.Decimal)
                .Add("@BestellUSt", MySqlDbType.Decimal)
                .Add("@BearbeitetAm", MySqlDbType.DateTime)
                .Add("@BearbeitetVon", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                .Add("@BestellID", MySqlDbType.Int32)
            End With
```

This list you want to reedit into a parameterlist of a Sub, i.e.

```
                Optional ByVal MandID As Integer = 0,
                Optional ByVal LiefID As Integer = 0, ...
```

In this case I would Find `.Add("@` and Replace it by `Optional ByVal` and with the wildcard capability I would Find `,*)` and Replace by `As Integer = 0`.

No matter how often I click on the `.*` Button on the Search/Replace Box it would not find that string. Any ideas how to acomplish that task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` button enables [Regular Expression matching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx), which is slightly different than simple wildcard matching. In Regex the * repeats the previous character or group 0 or more times, so in this case it would match `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)` (zero or more `,`'s).

Also important to note is that the Regex matching requires you to escape special characters such as `.` and `()`. The Visual Studio (since 2012) syntax is the same as the one used by the .NET Regular Expressions.

So you can still do what you always did, just with a slightly different syntax:

Search

```
,.*\)
```

Replace with:

```
 As Integer = 0
```

Using Regex you could also do the whole search and replace in one go:

Search:

```
 .Add\("@([^"]+)",.*\)
```

Replace with

```
 Optional ByVal $1 As Integer = 0,
```

Comment: Thank you jessehouwing. Yes, I know about regex but wildcards are common in DB searches and elswhere and are far more simple than regex where you have to learn a fairly complex syntax. And, as I said, wildcards were there in earlier versions... So can I interpret your reply so that wildacrds are gone...?

Comment: I suppose they are. Can't find that option anywhere in 2013 or 2015. I've always preferred the more powerful regex syntax. It allows you to do the whole search and replace in one go.

Comment: No doubt, regex is more powerful but there are so many flavours and so far I could not find a comprehensive tutorial on what is implemented in VS. Having a problem I search the net and there I find so many different approaches to the same thing but then most of them do not work in Search/Replace. And moreover at that moment I am rather concentrating on the development problems so trying out 5 different regex patterns is beyond my time (and nervs probably). Btw. your example worked fine, thanks again. :-)